# How to override addAddressByType() in class Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder as it is a private function?

Tags: magento2

I tried to override `addAddressByType()` function in `Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder` but I can't override this function only as it is a private function.

Then I tried to override whole class but getting the below error.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Interceptor

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Interceptor
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\Customer...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:150]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get('Magento\Customer...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:79]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\Customer...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:150]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get('Magento\Customer...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:79]
#5 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\Weee\Mod...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:150]
#6 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get('Magento\Weee\Mod...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:79]
#7 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\Weee\Mod...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]
#8 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\Weee\Mod...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/PluginList/PluginList.php:250]
#9 Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginList\PluginList->getPlugin('Ranosys\Subscrib...', 'weee-app-action-...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:119]
```

Please help to share your suggestions if there is any other better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy your vendor file from this location

> vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php

and then paste that here

> lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php

and change whatever function in this file.

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: Got this error PHP Fatal error:  
Cannot declare class Vendor\Module\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder, because the name is already in use in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento-project/app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php on line 431

Comment: I've updated my answer please review

Comment: Let me know if it will work for you then.

Comment: Thanks @Kishan, it worked ! could you help to elaborate it ?

Comment: Yes, Let me know. Approve my answer as well. Thanks.:)

Comment: I didn't understand how it is resolved, Could you elaborate it ?

Comment: Yes, But what you want there in that private function?

Comment: Actually I was unable to send email to multiple users at a time, as we can send by add($email) to single person but for multiple we need to pass array in add([$emails]), but this seems a bug in function addAddressByType(), it could not handle array, as it didn't go inside if condition ever, so I initialize $this->messageData[$addressType] = []; with an empty array before condition, then it worked, not sure if it is right.

Comment: Sure, Thanks in advance :)